# Google maps geocoding API does not return results that google maps returns

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I use google maps geocoding API v3 to get the gps coordinates for several addresses.

I don't know why for the address "Autostrada A22 Brennero-Modena, KM 308"

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=A22+Brennero-Modena+KM+308&sensor=true

it returns ZERO_RESULTS.

The problem is that if I search the same address on google maps it returns the correct result.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance,

Mario

Answer (score 3):

The API geocoder finds postal addresses. I'd guess you're trying to find the marker at 308km on that autoroute. The API geocoder can't do that. The [Places service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) *might* be able to.